# getElementsByTagName results in NullPointerException

Tags: javascript, android, nullpointerexception, titanium

consider the following code:

```
Ti.API.info(doc.getElementsByTagName('myTag'));
Ti.API.info(doc.getElementsByTagName('myTag').item(0));
```

the xml is valid and consists of a valid element "myTag". the result of the first line is as expected:

```
[INFO] [...] [Ti.NodeList]
```

the second line throws a

*Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException*

that confuses me, since that line works on ios fine. does anyone have an iidea what could cause that error?

Comment: Deductively, `.item(0)` part is causing the trouble. Have you tried checking if it is a valid notation in your failing environtment?

Comment: Do any of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85370/most-common-cause-of-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-dealing-with-xmls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved it with

```
if (doc.getElementsByTagName("myTag").length>0) {..}
```

so thanks for you advices :)

Comment: You could also check if `doc` is null or `doc.getElementsByTagName("myTag")` is null.